# SQL - Multiple Where Criteria on same field

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause

I remotely service a device with an Access MDB error log.  Using a custom web browser interface, limited SQL queries can be run again table EalInfo. The SQL string must all be on one line.

Using code below I can select records where ErrNum contains S_ which is great as it excludes many unneeded records.

```
Select 
    DTime,
    ErrNum,
    Param1,
    Param2,
    Controller,
    vxwErrNo,
    Info,
    [TmStamp]/86400 AS DAYS_SinceGantryPwrCycle,
    [TmStamp]/3600 AS HOURS,
    [TmStamp]/60 AS MINs 
from EalInfo 
where ErrNum like '%S_%' 
order by DTime Desc
```

But when I an additional filters (trying to exclude two common but unhelpful errors) no records are returned.

```
where ErrNum like '%S_%' 
    AND ErrNum <> "S_GAFSTARTUPTASK_DTH_BAD_PARAM" 
    AND ErrNum <> "S_DTH_USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED"
```

My SQL skills are pretty weak - I've googled and script kitty'ed a bit - but no joy.

Thanks

Comment: try 'single quotes' not "double quotes"

Comment: @RichBenner  . . . MS Access uses double quotes for strings.

Comment: aah, didn't know that, thanks @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, the wildcard for `like` is `*`, not `%`.  So, I would expect your query to look like this:

```
where ErrNum like '*S_*' and
      ErrNum <> "S_GAFSTARTUPTASK_DTH_BAD_PARAM" and
      ErrNum <> "S_DTH_USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED"
```

I should note that all these conditions will filter out `NULL` values of `errnum`.  If you are expecting `NULL`, then you need to check for that explicitly.

You should probably simplify the `<>` logic to:

```
where ErrNum like '*S_*' and
      ErrNum not in ("S_GAFSTARTUPTASK_DTH_BAD_PARAM", "S_DTH_USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED")
```

Comment: I wanted to answer that, but did some digging, and came across [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff192499.aspx), stating that it is valid in some circumstances (when using JET 4 or the OLE DB provider for JET). It likely is the cause, but I don't have a clue why that first query worked if it is.

Comment: Thank you for the replies - I will try your suggestions and report back here.  The LIKE code works and it is likely that older version of JET / OLE are being used.

Answer (score 0):

Not used Access for years so i may be wrong, but try out :

```
  SELECT
        DTime,
        ErrNum,
        Param1,
        Param2,
        Controller,
        vxwErrNo,
        Info,
        [TmStamp]/86400 AS DAYS_SinceGantryPwrCycle,
        [TmStamp]/3600 AS HOURS,
        [TmStamp]/60 AS MINs 

    FROM
        EalInfo 

    WHERE
        ErrNum LIKE '*S_*' 
               AND ErrNum <> 'S_GAFSTARTUPTASK_DTH_BAD_PARAM'
               AND ErrNum <> 'S_DTH_USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED'

    ORDER BY 
        DTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you** to all who answered.

Here is the code that worked for me.

This custom/limited SQL interface requires the SQL String to all be on one line - but I've attempted to format it here for readability :

Select

```
DTime
ErrNum
Param1
Param2
Controller
vxwErrNo
Info
[TmStamp]/86400 AS DAYS_SinceGantryPwrCycle
[TmStamp]/3600 AS HOURS
[TmStamp]/60 AS MINs
```

from EalInfo

Where

```
(ErrNum like '%S_%') AND 
(ErrNum not like '%S_GAFSTARTUPTASK%') AND 
(ErrNum not like '%S_DTH_USER_ALREADY%')
```

Order by DTime Desc